# remove_action() not working in WordPress Theme

Tags: wordpress

One of my plugin have this coding,

```
Class Afke{
public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'setup' ), -1 );
}

function setup() {
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_boxes' ) );
}
}
```

I tried by removing 'add_meta_boxes' in theme functions.php by adding the below code,

```
function remove_thematic_actions(){
 $bcatcf = new Afke();
remove_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $bcatcf, 'add_meta_boxes' ));
//remove_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_meta_boxes' );
}

add_action('init','remove_thematic_actions');
```

But not able to remove this action. Kindly suggest me.

Comment: How is the class `Afke` being instantiated in the plugin?

Comment: @brasofilo : Just by using new Afke;

Answer (score 0):

You have used ;

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_boxes' ) );
```

in `Afke` class, but there is no such a function `add_meta_boxes`. Use your function like this;

```
Class Afke{
  public function __construct() {
      add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'setup' ), -1 );
  }

  function setup() {
      add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'my_meta_box_function' ) );
  }

  function my_meta_box_function() {
    // do your things here
  }
}
```

And, in order to remove that action you need to use;

```
function remove_thematic_actions(){
  $bcatcf = new Afke();
  remove_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $bcatcf, 'my_meta_box_function' ));
}

add_action('init','remove_thematic_actions');
```

Comment: Hi Huseying Babal: Thanks for your reply. But it doesn't work.

Comment: You can see the setup is a function but it doesn't have valid callback.

Comment: @Huseying Babal: The Class name Afke is in Plugin file. So I can't able to add any function there.

Comment: Which plugin is it? Is it yours?

Comment: No, its a custom plugin. So they may update at any time. That's why I need to add in my theme functions.php.

Comment: Is there any function called `add_meta_boxes` in `Afke` class?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52767/discussion-between-vinoth-kumar-and-huseyin-babal)

Comment: Suppose if we disable the add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_boxes' ) ); in plugin, works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new instance, assigning the original to a variable allows to target it:

```
Class Afke2{
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'setup' ), -1 );
    }

    function setup() {
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_boxes' ) );
    }

    function add_meta_boxes()
    {
        add_meta_box(
            'test_metabox',
            __( 'Test meta box' ),
            function() { echo 'Hello world!'; },
            'post'
        );
    }
}
$myAfke = new Afke2;
```

Then, elsewhere, in another plugin or in the theme's `functions.php`:

```
function remove_thematic_actions(){
    global $myAfke;
    remove_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $myAfke, 'add_meta_boxes' ));
}
add_action('init','remove_thematic_actions');
```